# How to invoke a parent class constructor in php 7?

Tags: php

I have a `php code` as shown below in which I want to know how to invoke a class constructor at `Line A` in the code below:

```
class HelloWorld extends GoodWorld
{
    public function __construct($label, $name)
    {
        AwesomeWorld::AwesomeWorld($label, $name);     // Line A

        $this->inputType = 'password';
    }
    public function draw()
    {
        $this->value = '';
        GoodWorld::draw();
    }
}

class GoodWorld extends AwesomeWorld
{
    public $inputType;

    public function __construct($label, $name)
    {
        parent::__construct($label, $name);

        $this->inputType = 'text';
    }
}

class AwesomeWorld
{
    public $label;
    public $name;
    public $value;

    public $error;
    public $visible;

    public $form;

    public function __construct($label, $name)
    {
        $this->label = $label;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->visible = true;

        $this->error = false;
    }
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering if there are any changes I need to make at `Line A` in the `php code` above. Do I need to use `parent::__construct($label, $name)` at `Line A` ?

Comment: `AwesomeWorld::AwesomeWorld` - this is no longer a constructor. You must call `parent::__constructor($label, $name)`. Why you think `GoodWorld` should call parent constructor differently from `AwesomeWorld`?

Comment: `AwesomeWorld::AwesomeWorld` of course can't make sense, when your class does not even have a method by that name.

Comment: @CBroe It used to be constructor named after class name: https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.deprecated.php

Comment: Class `AwesomeWorld` is not the parent of `HelloWorld`. Its `GoodWorld` who is the parent of `HelloWorld`. Do I need to still use `parent::__construct($label, $name)` at Line A ? Just wondering.

Comment: @flash Yes, you must call `parent::__constructor` in each child class, otherwise parent call constructor will be overwritten and never called

Comment: If I use `parent::__constructor` at Line A, then class `GoodWorld` constructor will be called. Let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: 1. yes, you should use `parent::__construct($label, $name);` in HelloWorld class. it will also invoke constructor from AwesomeWorld. 2. the code on Line A does not make sense.

Comment: Not directly related to your code, but just for reference, if a child class doesn't declare a constructor at all, the parent one will be inherited (if visibility allows): https://3v4l.org/Em9hM

Comment: @Justinas yes, but that still required an actual method matching the class name to exist then - which is not the case here.

Comment: It's good that you're updating your code, but you should probably go all the way up to 8.x. 7.x is no longer a supported version. https://www.php.net/supported-versions

Comment: Why do you want to skip the constructor of the base class? This should be a smell. Maybe inheritance is not what you need. Inheritance is for specialization, not for code sharing. Is `GoodWorld` a more specific version of `AwesomeWorld`? The same for `HelloWorld` and `GoodWorld`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`function AwesomeWorld()` is no longer valid class [constructor](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.deprecated.php#migration70.deprecated.php4-constructors)

PHP allows to overwrite parent class constructor, and never call it. *But* if you wish to delegate passed values to parent class constructor, than each and every child class *must* call `parent::__constructor()` in it's own constructor:

```php
class HelloWorld extends GoodWorld
{
    public function __construct($label, $name)
    {
        parent::__construct($label, $name);     // Line A

        $this->inputType = 'password';
    }
}

class GoodWorld extends AwesomeWorld
{
    public $inputType;

    public function __construct($label, $name)
    {
        parent::__construct($label, $name);

        $this->inputType = 'text';
    }
}

class AwesomeWorld
{
    public $label;
    public $name;
    public $value;

    public $error;
    public $visible;

    public $form;

    public function __construct($label, $name)
    {
        $this->label = $label;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->visible = true;

        $this->error = false;
    }
}
```

---

You can simplify your code and skip all these constructors:

```php
class HelloWorld extends GoodWorld
{
    public $inputType = 'password';
}

class GoodWorld extends AwesomeWorld
{
    public $inputType = 'text';
}

class AwesomeWorld
{
    public $inputType = null;

    public $label;
    public $name;
    public $value;

    public $error;
    public $visible;

    public $form;

    public function __construct($label, $name)
    {
        $this->label = $label;
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yeah, it makes sense. I am wondering if there are syntax errors at Line A and Line B here https://3v4l.org/kXoEf ? I believe yes as constructor cannot have the same name as class name in php. I am wondering what modifications we need to make at Line A and Line B in the fiddle.

Comment: @flash You should switch parent and child classes in place, so it's defined before usage. https://3v4l.org/Mt47X And this is PHP8.1 version of same code: https://3v4l.org/ZT9gR#v8.1.16